# Why am I getting an uncaught typerror with mui-x/charts when running react app

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-x

I have installed material ui and the material ui charts and just wanted to test a chart in my react app. I get an uncaught TypeError. I have an app file where Im importing the bar that I just copied from the material ui homepage. Is there something else I need to install?

Check the image below to see the error message.

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tc78T.png)

I have searched for a solution with no result.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.